# makefile for multiple source

Tags: c, makefile

while learning make file  I am trying to write a make file for multiple source directories it seems i am wrong somewhere

Here is my code structure :

```
directory
├── common
│   └── fun2.c
├── inc
│   └── fun.h
└── src
    ├── fun1.c
    └── main.c
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CC= cc 
CFLAGS = -c -Iinc/
SOURCE=fun1.c\
       main.c\
       common\fun2.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCE:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE):$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< 
clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

I am getting error when running the makefile

Cannot find a rule to create target common\fun2.o from dependencies.
can someone point out what is wrong here

Comment: What environment (OS and toolchain) are you using? On Linux, directories are separated with forward slash "/" instead of backslash "\", so you could try changing that. If I am correct, the "make" does not see a file called "common\func2.c", hence it does not know how to produce "common\func2.o"

Comment: I am using unix aix

Comment: UNIX uses forward slashes. Try and change that, it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.c` sources are not in `directory`, rather in `directory/src`. Hence the fix:

```
SOURCE=src/fun1.c src/main.c common/fun2.c
```

`.c.o:` rule is unnecessary, [GNU make has a similar built-in rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). Alternatively, fix the rule to output into the correct directory:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

`-c` is an option for application `CC` to produce a `.o`, should never be in `CFLAGS`.

Targets `all` and `clean` should be `.PHONY`, i.e.:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Maxim But while doing so the object file for common/fun2,c is getting generated in src/ directory causing not found error to generate the executable hellomake all -f Makefile.mak
        cc  -c -Iinc/ main.c
        cc  -c -Iinc/ fun1.c
        cc  -c -Iinc/ common/fun2.c
        cc  -o hello main.o fun1.o common/fun2.o
cc: 1501-228 input file common/fun2.o not found

Comment: That should not be the case. Your objects are going to be `src/fun1.o src/main.o common/fun2.o`.

Comment: @BMM Updated the compilation rule for you.

Comment: Great Thanks a lot it is working . It is very silly to ask as i am new in learning It will be nice if you explain  Targets all and clean should be .PHONY, i.e.:

.PHONY: all clean

Answer (score 0):

```
CC= cc 
CFLAGS = -c -Iinc/
SOURCE= src/fun1.c src/main.c common/fun2.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCE:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE):$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< 
.PHONY: all clean
clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

If your project architecture "`bodyAndFit`" is just liking this:

```
bodyAndFit

|

|__Makefile

|__build

|__inc

|     |__bodyandfit.h

|__common

      |__main.cpp

|__src

     |__bodyandfit.cpp
```

Then, your Makefile is just liking this:

```
# -Only Separatedly Generate Object Files But Generate Main Object Add Directory Makefile-
# BIG BIG BIG NEWS
# This Makefile file : generate object file one by one directory 
# Also add main object sources files directory to generate main object
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is a Makefile fot separated multiple sources to build with VSCode on mac
# Thanks, Job Vranish.
# (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/26/makefile-c-projects/)
# Reference: Makefile Tutorial
# (https://makefiletutorial.com/)
# Reference: @yagiyuki from Qiita
# (https://qiita.com/yagiyuki/items/ff343d381d9477e89f3b)
# Reference: simonsso from Github
# (https://github.com/simonsso/empty-cpp-project/blob/master/Makefile)
# Reference: Chinese Website blogger CDNS
# (https://blog.csdn.net/qq_22073849/article/details/88893201)
# (1)Compiler
# clang++
CXX = clang++
# (2)Compile options
# -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -g
CXX_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -g
# (3)Build task directory path
# I do care about out-of-source builds
# ./build
BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
# (4)Source files directory path
# . and ./src
SRC_DIRS ?= .
SRC_DIRS_SRC ?= ./src
# (5)Library files directory path
LIBDIR :=
# (6)Add library files
LIBS :=
# (7)Target file, excutable file.
# main
TARGET ?= main
# (8)Source files(code), to be compiled
# Find source files we want to compile 
# *expression must around by single quotos
# ./src/bank.cpp ./src/main.cpp
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.s')
SRCS_SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS_SRC) -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.s')
# (9)Object files
# String substituion for every C/C++ file
# e.g: ./src/bank.cpp turns into ./build/bank.cpp.o
# ./build/bank.cpp.o  ./build/main.cpp.o
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp, ${BUILD_DIR}/%.cpp.o, $(notdir $(SRCS)))
OBJS_SRC := $(patsubst %.cpp, ${BUILD_DIR}/%.cpp.o, $(notdir $(SRCS_SRC)))
# (10)Dependency files
# which will generate a .d file next to the .o file. Then to use the .d files,
# you just need to find them all:
# 
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)
DEPS_SRC := $(OBJS_SRC:.o=.d)
# (11)Include files directory path
# Every folder in ./src find include files to be passed via clang 
# ./inc
INC_DIRS := ./bin
# (12)Include files add together a prefix, clang make sense that -I flag
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))
# LIBS_FLAGS := $(addprefix -L,$(LIBS)) 
# (13)Make Makefiles output Dependency files
# That -MMD and -MP flags together to generate Makefiles 
# That generated Makefiles will take .o as .d to the output
# That "-MMD" and "-MP" To generate the dependency files, all you have to do is
# add some flags to the compile command (supported by both Clang and GCC):
CPP_FLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP
# (14)Link: Generate executable file from object file
# make your target depend on the objects files:
${BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET} : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
# (15)Compile: Generate object files from source files
# $@ := {TARGET}
# $< := THE first file
# $^ all the dependency
# C++ Sources
#
# BREAK NEWS!!!
# If all the sources files including the main function are separated directory,
# Then you need to generate the object files via one by one directory
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o : $(SRC_DIRS)/common/%.cpp 
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(CXX_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o : $(SRC_DIRS_SRC)/%.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(CXX_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
# C Language Sources
# # CC := clang
# # C_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -g
# $(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: $(SRC_DIRS)/%.c
# $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
# $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.PHONY:  clean 
clean:
    $(RM) $(DEPS) $(OBJS) ${BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET} 

-include $(DEPS) 

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```

Change this to your needed `Makfile` :

```
# (1)Compiler
CC = gcc
# (2)Compile options
C_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -g
# (3)Build task directory path
# I do care about out-of-source builds
BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
# (4)Source files directory path
# ./common/func2.c ./src/func1.c ./src/main.c
SRC_DIRS ?= .
SRC_DIRS_SRC ?= ./src
# (5)Target file, excutable file.
# store in ./build/
TARGET ?= main
# (6)Source files(code), to be compiled
# Find source files we want to compile 
# *expression must around by single quotos
# ./common/func2.c ./src/func1.c ./src/main.c
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.s')
# ./src/func1.c ./src/main.c
SRCS_SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS_SRC) -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.s')
# (7)Object files
# String substituion for every C/C++ file
# ./build/func2.c.o ./build/func1.c.o ./build/main.c.o
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp, ${BUILD_DIR}/%.cpp.o, $(notdir $(SRCS)))
# ./build/func1.c.o ./build/main.c.o
OBJS_SRC := $(patsubst %.cpp, ${BUILD_DIR}/%.cpp.o, $(notdir $(SRCS_SRC)))
# (7)Dependency files
# which will generate a .d file next to the .o file. Then to use the .d files,
# you just need to find them all:
#  ./build/func2.c.d ./build/func1.c.d ./build/main.c.d
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)
# ./build/func1.c.d ./build/main.c.d
DEPS_SRC := $(OBJS_SRC:.o=.d)
# (8)Include files directory path
# Every folder in ./src find include files to be passed via gcc 
INC_DIRS := ./inc
# (9)Include files add together a prefix, clang make sense that -I flag
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))
# (10)Make Makefiles output Dependency files
# That -MMD and -MP flags together to generate Makefiles 
# That generated Makefiles will take .o as .d to the output
# That "-MMD" and "-MP" To generate the dependency files, all you have to do is
# add some flags to the compile command (supported by both Clang and GCC):
CC_FLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP
# (11)Link: Generate executable file from object file
# make your target depend on the objects files:
# gcc ./build/main.c.o ./build/func1.c.o ./build/func2.c.o ./build/main
${BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET} : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
# (12)Compile: Generate object files from source files
# $@ := {TARGET}
# $< := THE first file
# $^ all the dependency
# BREAK NEWS!!!
# If all the sources files including the main function are separated directory,
# Then you need to generate the object files via one by one directory
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o : $(SRC_DIRS)/common/%.c 
# gcc ./common/func2.c -o ./build/func2.c.o
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(C_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o : $(SRC_DIRS_SRC)/%.c 
# gcc ./src/func1.c -o ./src/func1.c.o
# gcc ./src/main.c -o ./src/main.c.o
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(C_FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
.PHONY:  all clean 
# Output target file: `./build/main`
all: ${BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET} 
# Delete dependency files, object files and target file
clean:
    $(RM) $(DEPS) $(OBJS) ${BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET} 
# include the dependecy files
-include $(DEPS) 
# if ./build directory not created, then create.
MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```